# Div Expand on click JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div tag :

```
<div id="tier1" class="tier1" >
    <a href="#" class="view">View All</a>
    </div>


.tier1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; 
    min-height: initial; 
    max-height: 245px; 
    padding: 0 0 8px;
}
```

And I want to expand this div beyond `max-height` whenever I click on `"View All"`

I am using this script :

```
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {


                                $('.view').click(function () {

                                    $('#tier1').animate(function () {
                                      height : 510 ;
                                    }, 1000);
                                });
                            });

                       </script>
```

But this expands till only max-height . I even tried setting maxHeight property in Script But then script didn't work at all.

Comment: Seems unlikely that runs at all, given `height : 510px ;` is a syntax error.

Comment: You can't use `animate(function()` the way you are doing it to animate, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('div.cls:first')
            $('.view').click(function () {
                $('#tier1.tier1').css("max-height", "1024px");
                $('#tier1').css("height", "510px").animate(function () {

                }, 1000);
            });
        });

                       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, you are expanding your div to a new height but you class stays the same your not expading the class so, it stays at the defined max-height. So you have to expand the class instead of the div or both in this case.

Comment: i use so way to much in my sentences :(

Comment: How can I expand my CSS class ?? Can you please help ?

Comment: Check the answers above, just  do  $('.tier1') instead of $('#tier1'). The  .  means a class the # means an id.

Answer (score 0):

```
function () {
    height: 500px
}
```

is incorrect for `.animate();`

Do it like this instead

```
  $('#tier1').animate({
       height: 500
  }, 1000)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Nrj5/1/)

[**Animate documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {


                                $('.view').click(function () {

                                    $('.tier1').animate(function () {
                                      $(this).css('max-height','510px');
                                    }, 1000);
                                });
                            });

                       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.view').click(function () {
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $("#tier1").toggle(function () {

            });
        });

    });
```